# Can anyone actually parse Aeromexico's excess baggage policy?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, aeromexico

Trying to determine how much I'd pay for 2 bags for a roundtrip YVR -> SCL flight, connecting in Mexico City.

My online itinerary just says "no info" for each bag, and gives [this link](https://www.aeromexico.com/us/travel-information/before-your-purchase/regulations-and-policies/baggage-policy.html) which at least for me just loads as a blank page on both Firefox and Chrome.

On the other hand, [this page](https://aeromexico.com/en-us/travel-information/baggage) seems to be what I want. At the very top, in the "Baggage Allowance" section, you can select your departure & arrival countries, and the table below updates. For example, when departing Canada and arriving in South America (except Brazil) in economy it looks like I get one checked bag free (note that this conflicts with what [seatguru says](https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/AeroMexico/baggage.php) which is 2 bags, but maybe they are just out of date).

OK, so how much for the second bag? Click "Excess Baggage Fees" in the header (I can't seem to link to this directly). You get a confusing table, the first few rows which look like this:

[image: Excess Baggage Table]

First, immediately above, it says *Select your route to consult our baggage fee schedule.* That kind of seems to imply that maybe the stuff I selected at the top regarding my route affects this table, but it doesn't: it's just an unchanging table.

I'm going to assume I'm interesting in the "Per piece at the airport" column, but I'll still note that even the other columns are confusing: there is "Per Volume" column, but no units? Is it just a fixed fee for any bag which exceeds the linear dimension rules or what?

OK, so how do I look up the right row? The heading says **Origin/Destination**. So which is it? Why is there a slash? I'm flying from Canada to South America, do I use my origin or my destination?

Let's assume I use the origin, and so the US & Canada row. It says **First Piece = 25 USD** - but from the "Baggage Allowance" section I'm pretty sure my first piece is free. What gives? Is it the first excess piece then (i.e., my second piece?). That interpretation doesn't make sense though given that the other rows don't have any "first piece" entry at all, so I think it really is the first piece (but perhaps the baggage allowance overrides it).

Ultimately, I'm guessing that my second piece of luggage will cost 55 USD, but any help in parsing this is still appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I still can't fully parse the table, but for the record, flying YVR -> MEX -> SCL, the fee was $55 USD for the second bag at the airport.

Answer (score 0):

The fee for additional baggage for flying between Canada and South America (excluding Brazil) is $80 USD for the second piece and $180 for each one after that.

[image]

In order to get this info you must select your origin and destination and then follow the excess baggage fees, finding the combination of routes required to go from Canada to South America.

Comment: I'm quite sure the from/to drop-down selections at the top don't change the table shown under excess baggage. I tried a few permutations at the table is unchanged. Did you find otherwise? Those selections, AFAICT, only effect the very top section dealing with baggage allowances.

Comment: The table is pretty clear now. It says *Multiple International Flights* with *From - to Central America, Caribbean, South America to USA / Canada*  which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Well I am not going "to" Canada, but "from", but perhaps that part is a typo/oversight? Too bad if that row applies: it seems nearly all of AMs interesting flights connect though MEX so it would apply almost all the time overriding the other rows. Also it's inconsistent with the earlier "baggage allowance" section which doesn't care if you have more than one international leg. @Itai

Comment: @BeeOnRope - They probably just forget to put To/From(instead of To) in the part since the beginning starts with To/From. Since most people buy round-trip tickets, it makes a lot of sense that allowance would be symmetric (it nearly always is), otherwise people can't get back with all their stuff or can't take as much as they are allowed to bring back!

Comment: @BeeOnRope (Cont'd) Actually the first row is for *within* Mexico, so it does not override. What does is the expandable point below the table with the heading *Flights Connecting In Mexico* which means that if you are staying more than 24 hours (so technically a stopover), *then* you apply the Mexco row (excluding if one of your end-points is in Brazil).

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's symmetric, and I had always assumed you just look up the baggage allowance once, based on the outbound part of your roundtrip and that the same applies to the return trip. So I guess under your interpretation, all of the first 7 rows are for flights pretty much with only one international leg, which mostly means to/from Mexico, since I doubt AM has many or any flights from non-Mexico countries to other continents. I guess I'll call them...

Comment: well based on the actual amount paid at the airport, 55 USD, it seems like a different row was used.

Comment: How long was your stop-over in MEX?

Comment: About 6 hours. @Itai

Comment: So I still can't parse it. Guess the answer to your question in no then :)

Comment: I guess so :). At least I'm happy it was the lower amount...